# Where am I going wrong with this list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to extract the 4 digit year (2000) from a string or return `None` or `NaN` if its not present.

```
w = 'A70-11370; reprint; rolled; 2000; 26.5 x 38.5'
```

I tried this but I get a syntax error.

```
[int(i) for i in w.split(';') if i.isnumeric() else np.nan]
```

Comment: The `if` following the `for` is part of the list comprehension syntax, not the beginning of an expression. (Conversely, `3 if True` is not a valid expression without an `else`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strip the whitespace and reposition the validation check:

```
In[0]: [int(i.strip()) if str(i.strip()).isnumeric() else np.NaN for i in w.split(';')]
Out[0]: [nan, nan, nan, 2000, nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

This must surely work

```
x=w.split('; ')

if x[3] == ' ':
    print ("null")
else:
    print (x[3])
```